# Is is possible to term query with asciifolding?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would need to match the whole field but using lowercase and asciifolding token filters. Is this possible in Elasticsearch?

For example, if I have a "Title" field for products and the product title is "Potovalni Kovček". And the user search query is "potovalni kovcek" then I need to return this product as the result. But only if the whole title matches the search query. If the user search query is "potovalni" or "Potovalni" or "kovcek" no results should be returned.

Can I create a term query with lowercase and asciifolding token filters? I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: It is always easier to get some help if you show some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to define the `title` field as a `keyword` and use a [custom normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) to do the job.

First let's create the index:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "exact": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "exact"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, we index a sample document:

```
PUT test/doc/1
{
  "title": "Potovalni Kovček"
}
```

Finally, we can search:

```
# Record 1 is returned
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title": "Potovalni Kovček" 
    }
  }
}

# Record 1 is returned
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title": "potovalni kovcek" 
    }
  }
}

# No record is returned
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title": "potovalni" 
    }
  }
}

# No record is returned
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title": "kovcek" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That will probably do. I didn't know that I could use a custom normalizer on a keyword field. Thank you! Will try it in a few hours.

Comment: Cool stuff, normalizers are around since [ES 5.2](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-5-2-0-released)!

Comment: Tried it and it worked like a charm. Thank you for helping!